# Concatenate columns together, columns can be null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to bring values together and copy it to a diffrent column.

```
COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |  COLUMN 3 | COLUMN 4 
Hallo      out         there      Hallo out there
My         NULL        name is    My name is
I'm        a           rabbit     I'm a rabbit
```

How to merge column 1, 2, 3 and copy it to column4 separated with space.

Columns can be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.table
  SET column4 = COALESCE(column1, '') 
      + COALESCE(' ' + column2, '')
      + COALESCE(' ' + column3, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2012

```
UPDATE table
SET Column4 = CONCAT(Column1 + ' ', Column2 + ' ', Column3)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes nice round number. Will be a shame when it changes!

Answer (score 2):

Just use + sign

```
  select ISNULL([COLUMN 1],'')+' ' +
         isnull([COLUMN 2],'')+' ' +
         isnull([COLUMN 3],'') 
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ISNULL`

```
UPDATE table
SET Column4 = 
ISNULL(Column1+' ','') + 
ISNULL(Column2+' ','') + 
ISNULL(Column3,'')
```

Or you could consider using a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

```
update yourtable SET COlumn4= ltrim(rtrim(isnull([COLUMN 1],'') +' '+isnull([COLUMN 2],'') +' '+  isnull([COLUMN 3],'')))
```

Comment: Now it will add additional spaces (e.g. if column1 and column2 are both null).

Comment: Pls check now.I have removed extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN1]),'')+' '+isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN2]),'')+' '+isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN3]),'')
from table

UPDATE table
SET COLUMN4 = isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN1]),'')+' '+isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN2]),'')+' '+isnull(convert(varchar(255),[COLUMN3]),'')
```

Above codes may not work depending on datatypes so you may convert it to varchar before.